# Cherrypy website does not work, where to find documentation?

Tags: python, cherrypy, doc

Today I found out that [cherrypy documentation page](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/index.html) does not work anymore. Does anyone know an alternative source of documentation?

Comment: The host just migrated a bunch of services to new servers. Might be a temporary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python
>>> import cherrypy
>>> help(cherrypy)
```

Might be a good option or http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/ works for me!

Comment: I get an error: Site is not configured.

Comment: Possibly you are behind a firewall or a nanny program that only lets you see sights that have been approved by an administrator.